# remove amp: from callback url

Tags: php, laravel, request

**request:**

```php
$success_urlt = $this->successUrl($request);
$success_url = urldecode($success_urlt);
$data = array(
    'amount' => $amount ,
    'api' => $api,
    'id' => $idorder,
    'name' => $user->first_name .' '.$user->last_name,
    'email' => $user->email,
    'app_name' => env('APP_NAME'),
    'app_logo' => $logo,
    'payment_title' => $title,
    'currency_code' => $currencycode,
    'success_url' => $success_url,
);

return view('frontend.payments.paywithMoyasar', compact('data'));
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIZX3.png)

As you can see in the picture, the inquiry is a correct callback link to the payment company

**response:**

After the success of the payment, it will be returned to the link, but it contains **&amp%3B**

```
https://newrviga.local/user/complete-order?amount=408&amp%3Bcode=undefined&amp%3Bpayment_type=moyasar&id=1ac42c5a-974f-4a9d-8e81-cdb64aa580e5&message=Succeeded%21%20%28Test%20Environment%29&status=paid&trx_id=hjoBEPkhSPhxKjvNtHQrJ
```

$request->all()

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zRpFZ.png)

as you see in above image

```
if ($request->payment_type == 'moyasar'){}
```

return null

is there any way to remove amp; from request

i do  urldecode() with callbacl link But it seems that the problem is in the payment company

Comment: That is URLEncoded.

Comment: can you share how you use `$data` in `paywithMoyasar.blade.php` ?

Comment: _"As you can see in the picture, the inquiry is a correct callback link"_ - well we can't actually tell whether its _content_ is correct or not. And the fact that you are needing to `urldecode` this before you add it to the array, is a bit suspicious IMHO. Why does `$this->successUrl()` not return a _proper_ URL, but something that you would need to encode first?

Comment: _"But it seems that the problem is in the payment company"_ - then you should probably contact them, and try to get this fixed. (Whether I'd want to use a payment provider that makes mistakes like that, would be another question.)